# Select like (2 parametros diferentes)

Tags: sql, select

Tenho uma tabela com diversos carros, preciso pegar apenas os que necessito.

**Exemplo:**
gol
fox
parati
kombi
voyage

Quero pegar apenas gol e kombi.

Estou usando o seguinte comando apra pegar onde tiver o valor GOL na minha tabela...

```
SELECT * FROM `volkswagen_base` WHERE link like '%gol%';
```

Como faço para pegar e exibir os valores gol e kombi?

Comment: Mas você não precisa usar o LIKE. você pode usar o WHERE link = 'gol' AND ou OR link = 'kombi'

Comment: éporque minha string é grande tipo "asdasd/gol&123/dasjd"

Comment: Ou se for usar o like, pode usar WHERE link LIKE '%gol%' AND link LIKE '%kombi%'

Comment: Tente dessa última forma

Comment: obrigado, deu certo

Comment: Ok, postei a resposta pra você... Se puder, dá um OK

Comment: No Check embaixo das setas ;)

Comment: Só para ficar claro @CharlesFay, mesmo que a string link seja grande ela pode conter Gol e Kombi ou apenas um dois dois?

Comment: ola so por curiosidade o link é o nome da coluna?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode elaborar seu SQL dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM volkswagen_base WHERE link LIKE '%gol%' OR link LIKE '%kombi%'
```

Comment: consegui usando o comando:  
SELECT * FROM volkswagen_base WHERE link LIKE '%gol%' OR link LIKE '%kombi%'

Obrigado

Comment: Por isso te perguntei qual valor o link armazenava, o AND não funcionaria, já que você quer registros que sejam Kombi ou Gol (qualquer um dos dois atende). Note que é uma boa prática colocar os LIKEs entre paranteses, assim: (LIKE '%gol%' OR link LIKE '%kombi%'). Isso deve ser feito por causa do OR. O AND tem precedencia sobre ele e se você tivesse outra condição com o AND em outro campo, então você pode ter problema caso não use o paranteses.

Comment: Exato, isso mesmo @cantoni

Comment: Essa foi simples assim.